# admin/commerce/products/add page says "You have not created any product types yet" when I have

Tags: 7, commerce

Somehow, the Drupal Commerce page at admin/commerce/products/add is failing to recognise that I have product types and is giving this misleading error:

> You have not created any product types yet. Go to the product type creation page to add a new product type.

From [reading this discussion](https://www.drupal.org/node/997444) and [a look at the code here](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/commerce/tree/modules/product/includes/commerce_product_ui.products.inc?id=78a038688464752ab499adda1a8a58f5195ef1bb) it looks like the Commerce module on this page bizarrely gets the list of product types from looking at the menus. There's a heap of "what worked for me was moving X to Y in the menus" but they all seem to be slightly different and match older menu naming conventions. [This issue](https://www.drupal.org/node/932194) appears related but isn't. I have editted the Commerce menu and would like to keep my editted menu how it is.

How can I make sure that Commerce recognised my product types on this page? What has to be where for this page to recognise product types (or even better, is there a way to make it happen the normal way via entities instead of via menus?)

I've also tried bypassing my broken admin/commerce/products/add page completely with a redirect, but the redirect is ignored.

I've also tried moving my Products > Create Item auto-generated menu links back under Store in the Management menu, and creating new menu links to those pages under Store in the Management menu, but neither works.

Answer (score 1):

Those admin pages are generally based on the menu, so I think it makes sense that the commerce module is using the menu to build it.

It doesn't have to be like that, though, you can change it up pretty easily:

```
function MYMODULE_menu_alter(&$items) {
  $items['admin/commerce/products/add']['page callback'] = 'MYMODULE_commerce_product_ui_add_page';
}

function MYMODULE_commerce_product_ui_add_page() {
  $types = commerce_product_types();  

  if (count($types) == 1) { 
    drupal_goto(_MYMODULE_commerce_product_admin_add_path(key($types)));
  } 

  return theme('MYMODULE_product_add_list', array('types' => $types));
}

function _MYMODULE_commerce_product_admin_add_path($type) {
  // Method taken from commerce_product_ui_menu()
  return 'admin/commerce/products/add/' . strtr($type, array('_' => '-'));
}

function MYMODULE_theme() {
  return array(
    'MYMODULE_product_add_list' => array(
      'variables' => array('types' => array()),
    ),
  );
}

function theme_MYMODULE_product_add_list($variables) {
  // Build up an HTML list of links based on $variables['types'], similar to theme_product_add_list()
}
```

Comment: I've tried using the menu callback to redirect to a page using `drupal_goto()` but, like the Global Redirect module redirect, it doesn't do anything - it seems like Commerce is somehow overriding all other instructions about what to do with this page?

Comment: Hmm, if I'm not mistaken we're just using the core menu functions, but I have personally seen the problem with nodes on a D7 site ... didn't realize it was related! Gives me a good lead to track that down.